# Geometric interpretation of the sine function

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to understand why $\sin(2\pi - \theta)$ represents a reflection across the $x$-axis of the segment from the origin represents an angle $\theta$. I can plug in possible values of $\theta$ and match them up geometrically, but I'm not seeing the "big idea" because this angle $2\pi - \theta$.

Comment: Do you see why $\sin$ has period $2\pi$?  If so, we have $\sin(2\pi-\theta) = \sin(-\theta)$.  So your question is: why is $\sin(-\theta) = -\sin(\theta)$ ?

Comment: @GEdgar Looking at it this way is very helpful. I understand that $\sin(-\theta) = - \sin(\theta)$, though I'm still not sure I understand why this represents a reflection across the $x$-axis.

Comment: Considering the angle on the unit circle this angle map corresponds to a reflection on the $x$ axis. The sine itself is of course odd-symmetric, so you get a point reflection in $(\pi,0)$.